# Why Is the Output of My Range Function Not a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the Python documentation, when I do range(0, 10) the output of this function is a list from 0 to 9 i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. However the Python installation on my PC is not outputting this, despite many examples of this working online.

Here is my test code...

```
test_range_function = range(0, 10)
print(test_range_function)
print(type(test_range_function))
```

The output of this I'm thinking should be the list printed, and the type function should output it as a list. Instead I'm getting the following output...

```
c:\Programming>python range.py
range(0, 10)
<class 'range'>
```

I haven't seen this in any of the examples online and would really appreciate some light being shed on this.

Comment: Have you read python doc for 3.x version? To get a list, you have to do `list(range(0, 10))`.

Comment: This was a change from 2.x to 3, documented here: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists .  Most of the time you're better off with an iterator anyway, but arbauthc's comment shows to create the list if you do need it.

Comment: If you're looking at the [Python documentation online](http://docs.python.org/3/index.html), always make sure you're reading the documentation for the version you're using. There's a little option menu in the upper-left corner of every page that shows, e.g., "2.7.5", which you can change to "3.3".

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I feel stupid not looking at the correct Python documentation but hopefully I won't make that mistake again!

Comment: @FiveAlive: Well, _I_ still make that mistake even though I know better. (Why is this `print` function printing a tuple when I'm passing it two values, neither of which is a tuple?!) How else do you think we all recognized the problem so quickly? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because `range` and other functional-style methods, such as `map`, `reduce`, and `filter`, return iterators in Python 3.  In Python 2 they returned lists.

[What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists):

> `range()` now behaves like `xrange()` used to behave, except it works with
>   values of arbitrary size. The latter no longer exists.

To convert an iterator to a list you can use the `list` function:

```
>>> list(range(5)) #you can use list()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually you do not need to materialize a range into an actual list but just want to iterate over it. So especially for larger ranges using an iterator saves memory.

For this reason [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range) in Python 3 returns an iterator instead (as [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) did in Python 2). Use `list(range(..))` if you want an actual list instead for some reason.

Comment: +1, This explains the reason for the change and why it's better. One small, subtle distinction - `range()` in 3.x returns an iterable, not an iterator. It has some advantages over a straight up iterator, like it's not exhausted when it's looped over, and it's a sequence, so you can slice it, etc... `range(10)[:5] == range(0, 5)`.

Comment: … and it also implements an O(1) `__contains__`. so when novices write `5 in range(1, 21, 2)` (as they always have), it's no longer a mistake, but instance good and perfectly idiomatic code.

Answer (score 1):

range() does not return an iterator, it is not iterator it is iterable. iterators protocol has 2 methods. `__iter__` and `__next__`

```
 r=range(10) 
  '__ iter __' in dir(r) # True
  `__ next __` in dir(r) # False
```

iterable protocol requires `__iter__` which returns an iterator.

```
r.__iter__()
# <range_iterator object at 0x7fae5865e030>
```

range() uses lazy eveluation. That means it does not precalculate and store `range(10)`. its iterator, range_iterator, computes and returns elements one at a time. This is why when we print a range object we do not actually see the contents of the range because they don't exist yet!.

Comment: See also: What are iterator, iterable, and iteration? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration)

Comment: See also: Iterable: [https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-iterable](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-iterable)